# Replacing Index of zoo object with new Index

Tags: r, indexing, zoo

I have a zoo object and I need to replace a specific index(#63) in my zoo to new Index.

My current zoo index is :

```
> index(MyZoo[63,])
[1] "2005-05-03 06:12:00 UTC"
```

My new Index is :

```
> tmp_index
[1] "2005-05-03 06:29:00 UTC"
```

The structure of both are the same :

```
> str(tmp_index)
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2005-05-03 06:29:00"

> str(index(MyZoo[63,]))
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2005-05-03 06:12:00"
```

I try this code :

```
index(MyZoo[63,]) <- tmp_index
```

**But the result is the same and it does not work**

```
> index(MyZoo[63,])
[1] "2005-05-03 06:12:00 UTC"
```

Please help me !!! How can I replace new Index to old one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
index(MyZoo)[63] <- tmp_index
```

Using an example data

```
index(MyZoo)[4] <-  tmp_index
MyZoo
#                    V1 V2 V3
#2005-05-03 04:25:00  6 13  2
#2005-05-04 04:25:00  5  8 12
#2005-05-05 04:25:00 15 14 15
#2005-05-03 06:29:00 11 14  3  ###changed
#2005-05-07 04:25:00 14  7  5
#2005-05-08 04:25:00 19 19 14
#2005-05-09 04:25:00  6  4  2
#2005-05-10 04:25:00 16  1 12
#2005-05-11 04:25:00 17 11 13
#2005-05-12 04:25:00  6  3  1
```

#### data

```
tmp_index <- as.POSIXct('2005-05-03 06:29:00', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

MyZoo <- structure(c(6L, 5L, 15L, 11L, 14L, 19L, 6L, 16L, 17L, 6L,
13L, 
8L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 5L, 
14L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 1L), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
c("V1", "V2", "V3")), index = structure(c(1115108700L, 1115195100L, 
1115281500L, 1115367900L, 1115454300L, 1115540700L, 1115627100L, 
1115713500L, 1115799900L, 1115886300L), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")
```